# Print with Lambda foreach in the same line with whitespace

Tags: java, lambda, foreach

I just started learning Lambda in java and got a little problem with the foreach method (`java.util.stream.IntStream.forEach(IntConsumer action)`). The common way I found to print with this method is like

```
forEach(System.out::println)
```

I wonder if there's way to print all the results in a single line like

```
System.out.print(result + " ");
```

Answer (score 9):

Yes, you can use a lambda expression :

```
someIntStream.forEach(result -> System.out.print(result + " "));
```

or, if you wish to still use a method reference, add a `mapToObj` step :

```
someIntStream.mapToObj(result -> result + " ").forEach(System.out::print);
```

Comment: or, as it's probably the intent, use collect(join(" ")) and then print.

Comment: @JBNizet That wouldn't work for `IntStream`. Also, it's `joining()`.

Comment: @shmosel it would work after transforming the IntStream to a Stream<String> using a mapToObj.

Comment: @JBNizet Then it wouldn't be an `IntStream`, would it? :)

Comment: Yes, it would: `System.out.println(IntStream.of(1, 2, 3).mapToObj(Integer::toString).collect(Collectors.joining(" ")));`

Comment: @JBNizet It wouldn't be once you called `mapToObj()`. My point is the same as yours: you would need to convert it before using a collector.

Comment: Well, yes, sure.

Comment: Further, you would need to collect all elements in the stream - the stream could be effectively infinite, in which case it is not appropriate to collect when the output can be generated in a streaming manner too.

Answer (score 4):

Many ways that avoid collection before output:

Lambda with overhead of two method calls, but avoiding object creation/reallocation on each entry:

```
intStream.forEach(s -> {
    System.out.print(s);
    System.out.print(" ");
});
```

Lambda incurring StringBuilder overhead:

```
intStream.forEach(s -> System.out.print(s + " "));
```

Using string format (likely similar overhead to the StringBuilder):

```
intStream.forEach(s -> System.out.printf("%d ", s));
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with a lamdba.

Example:

```
ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<String>();
array.add("Aaron");
array.add("N.");
array.add("Brock");

array.stream().forEach((s) -> System.out.print(s + " "));
```

Comment: In the asker's case, this results in boxing each int in the stream to an Int and then storing each boxed Integer in an array inside the ArrayList before printing. Presumably there is a good reason for using a stream, eg a limitless number of values, so collecting them is sub optimal, and boxing them is a potential waste of memory and GC time.

Comment: @JamesFry Good catch!  I changed the example to using a stream!

Answer (score 1):

`List l = Arrays.asList(1,2,13,41,6);
l.stream().map(result->result+" ").forEach(System.out::print);`

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

```java
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

// Without Any Space:

list.stream().forEach(System.out::print);

// With Next Line:

list.stream().forEach(System.out::println);

// With White Space

list.stream().forEach(e -> System.out.print(e + " "));
```